# solana locally compile config

Tags: debug

I attempted to compile the Solana binary locally (v1.16.25) using the ./cargo build command with the added --release option, as mentioned in the documentation. However, the resulting executable does not sync with the latest Solana blocks. Surprisingly, using the executable from the release works correctly and syncs with the latest Solana blocks. Could you provide the compilation options and versions of related software that you use?

Answer (score 2):

You've run the correct command by the looks of it. The script that builds everything for the release just ends up calling:

```
./cargo build --profile release --bin solana-validator
```

You can trace how it's built up and executed at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/3fa44e6fbe0c24da333f594b767eff69e0a71ec4/scripts/cargo-install-all.sh#L149

Be sure to use the built validator binary at `./target/release/solana-validator`